# Use of multiple imputation in R for two-level binary logistic regression model

Tags: r, missing-data, lme4, mixed-models, imputation

I am using the glmer function of the R library lme4 to fit a General Linear Mixed (GLM) models using the Laplace approximation and with a binary response variable, BINARY_r , say.  I have one level two fixed effects variables (‘FIXED’, say) and two level two cross-classified random effects variables (‘RANDOM1’ and ‘RANDOM2’, say). The level one binary response variable, BINARY_r, is nested separately within each of the two level two variables. The logit function is used as a link function for representing the non-Gaussian nature of the response variable. The interactive effect between the two random effects variables is represented by ‘RANDOM1:RANDOM2’. All three independent variables are categorical. The model takes the form,

BINARY_r ~ FIXED + RANDOM1 + RANDOM2 + RANDOM1:RANDOM2.

There are missing data for ‘FIXED’ and ‘BINARY_r’   and I wish to explore the improvement in the model through applying multiple imputation for each of these two variables.

I am very unclear, however, as to how to use MI to generate a new function in R using glmer which is identical to the original one but now includes imputed data for FIXED and BINARY_r. Can you help, please?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. I thought one of the attractions of mixed models was the fact that the algorithms could work around missing data.

Comment: Hello

I am very sorry but I don't know what you mean by "work around missing data".

Comment: It strikes me as quite problematic to first impute missing values in the outcome variable and then to predict the, now partially imputed, outcome variable.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on what you consider to make more sense. I understand that it is recognized practice to impute values for a response variable. Presumably, the idea is to create a better model, with better predictive capacity for individuals who do not fall into the study sample.

Comment: In the event that someone is able to help with my original query, here in addition, is an example of the type of R code that I am using for my current model:

Comment: @AlexW actually you are partially correct. Mixed model programs often fix the missing values for DVs, but not for predictors. There is actually a healthy portion of this discussed in *Flexible Imputation of Missing Data* by the creator of `mice`.